# How remove or change <title> tag in wordpress using plugin , add_filter ?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, title, add-filter

I need change or remove `<title>` tag in wordpress using plugin
for example `<title> My old title </title>` => `<title> New title </title>`

I try it

```
function plugin_title($content){
    $content=str_replace('My old title','New title',$content); 
    return $content;
}

add_filter('wp_head','plugin_title');
```

//  but it doesn't work .   Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: Not really, this is Wordpress-specific.

Comment: @cbuckley as long is related to HTML parsing, is not that hard to convert it DomDocument

Comment: @ajreal: No. It has as much to do with how Wordpress implements plug-ins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the wp_title hook

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_title', 20 );

function custom_title( $title ) {
    return str_replace('My old title', 'New title', $title); 
}
```